# How do can watch DOM Object properties?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to watch a DOM node property but I can't seem to get it to work.

Within my widget, I've tried the following.

```
startup: function() {
  this.inherited(arguments);

  // First try using the dojo 1.6 watch.
  // I'm setting the property of the widget
  // to reference the DOM node's offsetWidth property
  this.width = this.domNode.offsetWidth;
  this.watch("width", function() {
    console.debug('Width changed to ' + this.domNode.offsetWidth )
  })

  // Does this.width contain a reference or a copy of this.domNode.offsetWidth?

  // Second try, the Mozilla watch
  this.domNode.watch("offsetWidth", function() {
    console.debug('Width changed to ' + this.domNode.offsetWidth )
  })
}
```

Comment: Objects no longer have a `watch` method.

Comment: Can only be done cross-browser if the attribute is an event, e.g.: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm would like to watch a DOM node
>   property but I can't seem to get it to
>   work.

You can't get it to work by adding Mozilla's `watch` directly to the DOM node.

At http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/ mention is made of using `setInterval`, `onpropertychange` (IE only), and `DOMSubtreeModified` (there are other such standard DOM modification events like `DOMAttrModified`, but you'd have to check browser support). The standard DOM modification events only work if the DOM attribute is changed, not the equivalent property (though you can trigger a mutation event from JS by `initMutationEvent`):

```
<input />
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  var ct=0;
  document.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function () {
      alert('Value modified ' + (++ct) + ' times');
  }, false);

  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

  input.setAttribute('value', 5); // Triggers the event
  input.value = 15; // Though it sets the value, it doesn't trigger the event

};
</script>
```

> // First try using the dojo 1.6 watch.
>   // I'm setting the property of the
>   widget   // to reference the DOM
>   node's offsetWidth property
>   this.width = this.domNode.offsetWidth;
>   this.watch("width", function() {
>       console.debug('Width changed to ' + this.domNode.offsetWidth )   })

You can monitor the setting of the width property here using the Dojo API, but this does not appear to track the DOM node for you (though http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/widget-watch seems to suggest it does). For example, you can do:

```
widget.set('width', 100);
```

and then your `watch` event above could be modified to dynamically change the DOM `width` (but not the `offsetWidth` since that is a read-only property).

Still, it appears you're trying to detect automatic`offsetWidth` calculation changes, not your own changes. The best solution for you at this point seems to me to be `setInterval`.

> // Does this.width contain a reference
>   or a copy of this.domNode.offsetWidth?

A copy since this.domNode.offsetWidth is a number and in JavaScript, non-object types will always get copied by value.

> // Second try, the Mozilla watch
>   this.domNode.watch("offsetWidth",
>   function() {
>       console.debug('Width changed to ' + this.domNode.offsetWidth )
>   })

If this were able to work (and it doesn't), you'd need to use `this.offsetWidth` inside the function since Mozilla sets the callback `this` to that of the object being watched.

Answer (score 1):

`watch` in Dojo is only defined for `dojo.Stateful` objects, and also in dijit widgets (which all inherit from dojo.Stateful).

You cannot watch for property changes in a plain DOM node in a cross-browser way without resorting to browser-specific quirks.  Events are not properties of a node.