# JavaScript event listener for non-input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)
> [How do can watch DOM Object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520346/how-do-can-watch-dom-object-properties)

Is there a way to bind events to non-input-type elements? For example, binding an event to an anchor element that fires when the href attribute is changed.

Comment: Are you talking about img and script elements? If you change their src, they should trigger a load event after the new url is loaded.

Comment: How is the src attribute being changed on your element?

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's an answer!

Comment: Ok - changed my example as I'm actually not dealing with src and can't use that solution.

Comment: In that case, you're pretty much stuck with polling in today's world.

Comment: I totally forgot you can bind click/mousemove to almost any kind of element. Need more coffee :) My question would probably be more useful if I concentrated on the change event, which was my original interest.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind handlers to all kinds of events on non-input elements (`click`, `mousemove`, etc.). But there is no (consistent cross-browser) event raised when an attribute changes (such as your example of an `href` attribute on a link). Some attributes (like `src`) will cause an event (like `load`) as a secondary thing, as [bfavarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825789/bfavaretto) pointed out.

(There's a now-dead proposal for ["mutation" events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) on elements, including attribute changes [mutations], but it was never broadly supported. There's a [newer proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver), but it is also not [yet] broadly supported.)

You can, of course, use polling: Save the old value, and check back periodically (via `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) to see if it has changed. Unless you're checking a **lot** of elements and need to check them near-constantly, this needn't be a performance problem.

Answer (score 3):

[DOM Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) can do this, but they're very new and not well supported at the time of writing.

Are you writing an extension or similar (ie, you don't control that code that's modifying the DOM)? That's one of the more common use cases for these events - where you don't control the code that's changing the DOM. I've used this before with the [Mutation Summary](http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/) which has worked well in Chrome.

If you do control the code that's modifying the DOM - ie you're modifying the attribute yourself on your own web site - you might wish to simply fire off a custom event of your own when you modify the attribute.

Comment: That's the thing I was thinking of!

Comment: Pretty good idea, but I don't have control over the code that's modifying the attribute, thus I cannot fire an event.

Comment: Then go load Mutation Summary. That's what it's for!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `DomSubtreeModified` listener to an ancestor, or you could use `watch` on the `src` property of the DOM object if it is supported in the browser you are using.

```
myImage.watch("src",function(id, oldval, newval){
    document.write("src changed!");
    return newval;    
});
```